# Dividing into 2 teams

Tags: probability

In how many ways can $22$ people be divided into $ 2 $ cricket teams to play each other?

Actual answer : $\large \dfrac{1}{2} \times \dbinom{22}{11}$

My approach :

Each team consists of $11$ members. Number of ways to select a team of $11$ members = $ \dbinom{22}{11}$

Number of ways by which $22$ people can be divided into $2$ cricket teams = $\dbinom{22}{11} \times 1$ (since the remaining 11 members will automatically fall into the 2nd team).

I appreciate if somebody would be able to explicate the role of $ \large \dfrac{1}{2} $ here.

Comment: Because who's on blue team and who's on red team is irelevant. Only who is on team with who matters.

Comment: On how many ways can $2$ people be divided into $2$ teams? In $\binom{2}{1}=2$? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

Another way: It so happens that one of the $22$ people is the Queen, who of course gets to choose the people who will be on her team. This can be done in $\binom{21}{10}$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you choose $ \large11 $ people out of $ \large 22 $ people, there is a complementary team formed on the other side, that is, the other $ \large 11 $ people also form a team. So we overcount by a factor of $  \large 2 $, that is, we count every time twice.

For example, let $ \large 1, 2, 3, 4 $ be the group of people to choose from. We can choose $ \large 2 $ players in $ \large \dbinom{4}{2} $ ways but we overcount by a factor of $ \large 2 $.

Here, if we choose $\large  2 $ teams, we get

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

The complementary teams in every case are

```
(1, 2) (3, 4)
(1, 3) (2, 4)
(1, 4) (2, 3)
(2, 3) (1, 4)
(2, 4) (1, 3)
(3, 4) (1, 2)
```

We notice that we have counted every time twice. For example, $ \large (1, 2) $ and $ \large (3, 4) $ should not be counted separately, as when $ \large (1, 2) $ occurs, we automatically get $ \large (3, 4) $.

We can extrapolate this for the $\large 22 $ players.